# What are all the escape characters?

Tags: java, string, escaping

I know some of the escape characters in Java, e.g.

```
\n : Newline
\r : Carriage return
\t : Tab
\\ : Backslash
...
```

Is there a complete list somewhere?

Comment: This is in the [Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

Comment: @user207421 though it is nice for the rest of us to find while googling.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You can find the full list [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

- `\t`    Insert a tab in the text at this point.
- `\b`    Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
- `\n`    Insert a newline in the text at this point.
- `\r`    Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
- `\f`    Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
- `\s`    Insert a space in the text at this point.
- `\'`    Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
- `\"`    Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
- `\\`    Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

Comment: The list is missing Unicode and octal escapes: \u1234 \012 \01 \0

Comment: Here is the [paragraph for the unicode escape sequence in the java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)

Comment: It's also missing the bell character `\a` and the null character `\0`.

Comment: `\a` does not compile in javac 1.8.0_20: `illegal escape character: String test = "\a";`

Comment: "Unicode escapes are pre-processed before the compiler is run." -- [Mark Peters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866219/1048186).  So they are different from the standard String escapes listed here. Thanks Jan for the comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29064518/1048186)

Comment: When speaking of Java 16, this list is all but complete. I assume the oracle tutorials are not updated on a regular basis. Your better bet is to check the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)

Comment: what about `\s` (space)```jshell> "\s".charAt(0) == ' '
$1 ==> true```

Answer (score 50):

```
Java Escape Sequences:

\u{0000-FFFF}  /* Unicode [Basic Multilingual Plane only, see below] hex value 
                  does not handle unicode values higher than 0xFFFF (65535),
                  the high surrogate has to be separate: \uD852\uDF62
                  Four hex characters only (no variable width) */
\b             /* \u0008: backspace (BS) */
\t             /* \u0009: horizontal tab (HT) */
\n             /* \u000a: linefeed (LF) */
\f             /* \u000c: form feed (FF) */
\r             /* \u000d: carriage return (CR) */
\"             /* \u0022: double quote (") */
\'             /* \u0027: single quote (') */
\\             /* \u005c: backslash (\) */
\{0-377}       /* \u0000 to \u00ff: from octal value 
                  1 to 3 octal digits (variable width) */
```

The [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) is the unicode values from 0x0000 - 0xFFFF (0 - 65535). Additional planes can only be specified in Java by multiple characters: the egyptian heiroglyph A054 (laying down dude) is `U+1303F` / `&#77887;` and would have to be broken into `"\uD80C\uDC3F"` (UTF-16) for Java strings. Some other languages support higher planes with `"\U0001303F"`.

Comment: The existing answer does not address unicode and octal escape sequences in Java.

Comment: `\u000a` does not seem to work -> `- invalid character constant` 

see more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866187/why-cant-i-use-u000d-and-u000a-as-cr-and-lf-in-java)

Comment: @Jan It is working, perhaps too well. Unlike, for example, `\r` and `\n`, unicode escapes are pre-processed before the compiler is run as the question you linked to specifies. As such, it's inserting a literal line feed into your code and failing because of it. However, the escape code is "working" as it was intended to work in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Well additionally, older versions of Java supported `\v` for form feed.

From: java/util/regex/Pattern.java:

```
2600         case 'v':
2601             // '\v' was implemented as VT/0x0B in releases < 1.8 (though
2602             // undocumented). In JDK8 '\v' is specified as a predefined
2603             // character class for all vertical whitespace characters.
2604             // So [-1, root=VertWS node] pair is returned (instead of a
2605             // single 0x0B). This breaks the range if '\v' is used as
2606             // the start or end value, such as [\v-...] or [...-\v], in
2607             // which a single definite value (0x0B) is expected. For
2608             // compatibility concern '\013'/0x0B is returned if
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, below is a link of docs.Oracle where you can find complete list of escape characters in Java.

Escape characters are always **preceded with "\"** and used to perform some specific task like go to next line etc.

**For more Details on Escape Character Refer following link:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

These are escape characters which are used to manipulate string.

```
\t  Insert a tab in the text at this point.
\b  Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r  Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
\f  Insert a form feed in the text at this point.
\'  Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
\"  Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
\\  Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.
```

Read more about them from here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html