# assigning special characters such as " in java

Tags: java, string

How can I assign this string in a Java String?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

thanks

Comment: See [What are all the escape characters in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java)

Comment: If applicable on your environment, rather use a view technology like JSP.

Comment: You could have at least tried searching for the answer first.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I wasn't aware of the term "escape characters"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String s = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">";
```

i.e. replace the `"` characters with the escaped form, `\"`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use single quotes instead of double quotes. Then it wouldn't be an issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
```

Answer (score 0):

And you may read the string from an external source like a file, a database or from a JTextField or something similar. Maybe from an Url. :)