# A commented statement with a unicode new line character

Tags: java, unicode, newline

Let's have a look at the following Java code.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //\u000d System.out.println("It works fine.");
    }
}
```

In the preceding code snippet, the only line inside the `main()` method contains a unicode new line character, `\u000d` . It displays the specified message "*It works fine.*" even though that line is commented out. How does it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use \u000D and \u000A as CR and LF in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866187/why-cant-i-use-u000d-and-u000a-as-cr-and-lf-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little-known feature of the Java language is that Unicode escape sequences are processed anywhere in source code, before any other parsing.

That's a real newline.

You can even write an entire Java program out of nothing but escape codes.

Comment: It can even have unicode identifiers, like class БлаБла {} . I do NOT RECOMENDED using them though