# Getting error on commented line

Tags: java

```
  class k{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   //('\u000d'); 
   }
}
```

In class k after main i have commented out line number 3 but still getting error unclosed character literal ,what could be the reason for it?

Comment: unclosed character literal

Comment: Please post the *exact* code which causes that error.

Comment: //('\u000d'); this line

Comment: What are you trying to do here anyway?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866187/why-i-cant-use-u000d-and-u000a-as-cr-and-lf-in-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unicode characters are parsed very early in the Java compilation,  anyway `\u000d` isn't a valid character.

```
// The other style comments work.
/*('\u000d'); */
```

**Edit**

\u000d is converted into a newline, which ends your comment...

```
//('\u000d');
```

gets converted into

```
    //('
') // <-- bare line with ')
```

which isn't a valid character constant.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "\u000d isn't a valid character"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Edited to add more explanation

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `'\u000d'` is a newline character. The compiler sees the single line of code as two lines:

```
//('
');
```

This is why you get the error. The second line has an opening single-quote, but no closing one to match.

Answer (score 3):

It's a character literal. `\u000d` means "newline". While being in a commented line may seem to you like nothing in it is handled, this happens:

```
original : {
  //('\u000d');
}

pre-compile : {
  //('
'); // <- This is syntax error!!!
}
```