# New line character not found while getting string from database

Tags: java, string, newline

I saved a line by line string in database . But when accessing the string from DB ,i was not able to get the line by line string. Instead the whole string is coming as one single block. What could be the reason? Any alternatives?

Comment: @user1722444 I'm not quite sure what you mean. A string value is still a single "block", even if it contains line feeds. Do you mean that the line feed is missing, or is getting all text at once - including a line feed - the unexpected thing?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : 'line1 \n line2 \n ... ' etc is the saved string. But i'm getting 'line1line2' in return

Comment: @jWeavers: Its an Oracle database

Comment: It can't be, Always select query return 'line1 \n line2 \n ... ' as it is. You can split your string later

Answer (score 1):

You might have to unescape the `\n` from string retrieved from databse.
You can use [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29).
Similar question : [Java is not treating "\n" as new line when retrieved from Database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678768/java-is-not-treating-n-as-new-line-when-retrieved-from-database-column)