# String cannot contain java regex metacharacter

Tags: java

String should not contain java regex meta character like \d,\D all..
How we can handle programatically. It can contain *, . ? , + but not the java regex metacharacter.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What do you need this string for? show us a use case and what have you tried so far.

Comment: `.`, `*`, `+`, and `?` are all regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s="\\d\\D";
    if(s.contains("\\d")||s.contains("\\D")||s.contains("\\w"))
    {
        System.out.println("Should Not Contain");
    }

}
```

Something like this...
O/p : Should Not Contain

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [Pattern#quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). It returns a String with escaped regex special character for use as literal.

You can also use [Matcher#quoteReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) to escape special characters in a String that is intended to be used as replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for escape characters in Java so you can write \d and \D in a string? ("\d" and "\D").

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

[What are all the escape characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java)