# Removing characters from string efficiently

Tags: java, string

This may sound like a very simple question but how do you remove multiple different characters from a string without having to write a line for each, which is what I have laboriously done. I have written a string example below:

```
            String word = "Hello, t-his is; an- (example) line."

            word = word.replace(",", "");
            word = word.replace(".", "");
            word = word.replace(";", "");
            word = word.replace("-", "");
            word = word.replace("(", "");
            word = word.replace(")", "");
            System.out.println(word);
```

Which would produce "`Hello this is an example line`". A more efficient way is?

Comment: Try using String's `replaceAll` method - http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-strip-characters-string-letters-numbers-replace

Comment: Do you know by advance the list of characters you have to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although no more efficient than the original `replace` technique you could use

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
```

to use a simple expression using `replaceAll` with a wider range of characters replaced

Comment: Why do you append '+' (plus) to the regexp?

Comment: @Reimeus, The plus is fine.  Replacing an entire run of matching characters with the empty string is just a more efficient way of replacing each matching character individually with the empty string.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
word = word.replaceAll("[,.;\\-()]", "");
```

Note that special character `-` (hyphen) should be escaped by double backslashes, because otherwise it is considered to construct a range.

Comment: What would be the smartest way to escape a hyphen in a 'String', if you have a variable list of characters to remove?

Comment: ok, found it: [String cannot contain java regex metacharacter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215512/string-cannot-contain-java-regex-metacharacter/20215617#20215617)

Answer (score 2):

Without (ab)using regex, I would do that way:

```java
String word = "Hello, t-his is; an- (example) line.";
String undesirable = ",.;-()";

int len1 = undesirable.length();
int len2 = word.length();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len2);
outer: for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
    char c = word.charAt(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (c == undesirable.charAt(i)) continue outer;
    }
    sb.append(c);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

The advantage is performance. You don't need the overhead of creating and parsing a regular expression.

You could encapsulate that in a method:

```
public static String removeCharacters(String word, String undesirable) {
    int len1 = undesirable.length();
    int len2 = word.length();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len2);
    outer: for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
        char c = word.charAt(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
            if (c == undesirable.charAt(i)) continue outer;
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String removeSpecialCharacters(String word) {
    return removeCharacters(word, ",.;-()");
}
```

And then, you would use it this way:

```java
public static void testMethod() {
    String word = "Hello, t-his is; an- (example) line.";
    System.out.println(removeSpecialCharacters(word));
}
```

Here is a performance test:

```java
public class WordTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iterations = 10000000;
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            testAsArray();
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            testRegex();
        }
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            testAsString();
        }
        long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Without regex, but using copied arrays: " + (t2 - t1));
        System.out.println("With precompiled regex: " + (t3 - t2));
        System.out.println("Without regex, but using string: " + (t4 - t3));
    }

    public static void testAsArray() {
        String word = "Hello, t-his is; an- (example) line.";

        char[] undesirable = ",.;-()".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.length());
        outer: for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            for (char h : undesirable) {
                if (c == h) continue outer;
            }
            sb.append(c);
        }
        sb.toString();
    }

    public static void testAsString() {
        String word = "Hello, t-his is; an- (example) line.";

        String undesirable = ",.;-()";
        int len1 = undesirable.length();
        int len2 = word.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len2);
        outer: for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
            char c = word.charAt(j);
            for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
                if (c == undesirable.charAt(i)) continue outer;
            }
            sb.append(c);
        }
        sb.toString();
    }

    private static final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[,\\.;\\-\\(\\)]");

    public static void testRegex() {
        String word = "Hello, t-his is; an- (example) line.";
        String result = regex.matcher(word).replaceAll("");
    }
}
```

The output on my machine:

```
Without regex, but using copied arrays: 5880
With precompiled regex: 11011
Without regex, but using string: 3844
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, regexes are computed at compile time, not runtime. By the time the string is actually tested against the regex, the regex has been converted into a giant table, and the testing is extremely fast.

Comment: `.toCharArray()` duplicates the string's internal array; it's better here to use `CharBuffer.wrap()` and `.get()` from it instead.

Comment: Also, the performance test is pretty much worthless; you only perform the operation 10000 times, which is precisely the number of times Hotspot will run some code before deciding to optimize it...

Comment: @fge Is it better now? `CharBuffer` just delegates it to the `charAt` method under the hood, so it is easier to go directly to the `String`.

Comment: @AaronSmith See my performance test. I invite you to try it out on your machine also.

Comment: Sure, `CharBuffer` delegates; but `.toCharArray()` duplicates the whole char array. `CharBuffer` doesn't do that.

Comment: @fge And now, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a regular expression with Java's String.replaceAll method:

```
word = word.replaceAll(",|\.|;|-|\(|\)", "");
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, | means "or". So we are essentially saying , or . or ; or - or ( or ).

See more: [Java documentation for String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

**Edit:**

As mentioned, my previous version will not compile. Just for the sake of correctness (even though it has been pointed out that this is not the optimal solution), here is the corrected version of my regex:

```
word = word.replaceAll(",|\\.|;|-|\\(|\\)", "");
```

Comment: That's quite a waste; you use an alternation where a simple character class would have been enough. Also, this won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to do this with minimal effort; the `toRemove` string contains all character you don't want to see in the output:

```
public static String removeChars(final String input, final String toRemove)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    final CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.wrap(input);

    char c;

    while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
        c = buf.get();
        if (toRemove.indexOf(c) == -1)
            sb.append(c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you use Java 8 you can even use this (unfortunately there's no `CharStream` so the casts are necessary...):

```
public static String removeChars(final String input, final String toRemove)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());

    input.chars().filter(c -> toRemove.indexOf((char) c) == -1)
        .forEach(i -> sb.append((char) i));

    return sb.toString();
}
```