# Dealing with backslash

Tags: java, javascript, esapi

I have some text, which I want to display using java (on jsp page) and using javacript. but when I use \ then text in javascript is shown correctly but java shows it with one more back slash. the text is the same, is there some way how I can have them displayed the same way?

Comment: Could you show us an example, maybe a printscreen and a snippet of your javascript and java code?

Comment: Has your question been answered yet?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called an "escape sequence" for a variety of security reasons many characters do not print when written directly in a string literal.

Common c style escape sequences are prefixed with '\' (backslash character) followed by the character to escape

'\\' is the character sequence you're looking for to print a single '\' character.

[wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

see older stackoverflow [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java).

```
 - \t Insert a tab in the text at this point.
 - \b Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
 - \n Insert a newline in the text at this point.
 - \r Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
 - \f Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
 - \' Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
 - \" Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
 - \\ Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.
```