# Regex illegal escape character

Tags: java, regex, escaping, character

```
String[] tokens = infix.split("[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)? | sin | cos | tan | log | \^ | sqrt | \( | \) | \+ | \- | \* | \/");
```

When I compile this, it says I have an illegal escape character at "\^", I'm trying to tell it to ignore the special character "^" and view "^" as an actual String, don't I have the syntax right?

Comment: Have you looked into valid String **escape sequences** in **String literals**?

Comment: yes I have, i did [\^], and (\^)

Comment: You obviously didn't. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

In java, you need to escape the escapes. Essentially, you must use *double* backslashes for string literals:

```
String[] tokens = infix.split("[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)? | sin | cos | tan | log | \\^ | sqrt | \\( | \\) | \\+ | \\- | \\* | /");
```

Note that you *don't* escape forward slashes in java (regex or not).

As an aside, you regex may be simplified to:

```
String[] tokens = infix.split("[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)? | sin | cos | tan | log | sqrt | [()+*-] | /");
```

Comment: hmm i tried that, but my calc GUI still crashed when I used it

Comment: @user3427042 I just tested the regex and it compiled (ie executed) OK. I think there is a problem with the regex not related to escaping. I suspect you don't want all those spaces in there.

Comment: "[()+*-]" since those are all special characters, wouldn't I need a "\" before each one to escape its special regex meaning?

Comment: No. Characters in a character class don't need escaping, except for very few special cases.

Comment: oh ok tysm, and so could I include a "^" and "/" in there too?

Comment: Yes, although the carat `^` should not be the first character (otherwise you'll create a *negated* character class). The forward slash is not a special character at any time, nor does it have any regex meaning in any language (some languages use the forward slash to *delimit* a regex, but it's not *part* of the regex - on those languages, you need to escape the slash to express a literal slash). Note that the minus sign must be first or last in a character class, otherwise it defines a character *range*, eg `[a-z]` means any lowercase letter, but `[az-]` means "a, z or dash"