# Assert Equals having issue in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test case, in which I'm not able to compare two strings only because of `</>` tag inside the object.

### My output is

```
{"description":"<p>License forms information can be download as attachments<\/p>"}
```

### My expected output is:

```
"{\"description\":\"<p>License forms information can be download as attachments</p>\"}";
```

The only place where I'm facing problem is at `</p>` tag. When I change to `<\/p>` it throws me syntax error.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My code

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://myip:8080/Kalgudi/restService");
    ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);        
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output);

    System.out.println("Json object is:"+json.getJSONObject("6824"));


    String expected = "{\"description\":\"<p>License forms information can be download as attachments</p>\"}";




    assertEquals(expected, json.getJSONObject("6824"));
```

Comment: Um, maybe the test case code would be a good idea?

Comment: Just try this http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-escape-a-string-for-java.html

Comment: @cyborg, updated with my code. Please check it.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way this can be answered as we simply have no idea what your webservice is doing to produce that JSON with the incorrect closing tag. That is presumably the system you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess because there isn't really enough information to say anything else that you are not escaping your strings correctly which looks to be succinctly answered in [What are all the escape characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java). Doesn't really seem to be a problem with assertions, equality or unit tests.