# how to escape backslash when creating a url

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string  `s = "sunil\"`  and `t = "sunil/"`

When i create URI from the string, I get some abnormal values

```
http://admin:sunil%5c
```

So my url is not getting executed properly.

I want my url to be `http://admin:sunil\` or `http://admin:sunil/`

My URL creation is like this:  http://userid:password@host:port

where in my password string contains "\" character. So it fails to create the URL correctly

please give information how to retain `\` and `/` inside a string when creating a url.

i dont know if i have to use replace() in the string.

Comment: how come you assign `"sunil\"` to a variable.

Comment: how are you creating url ?

Comment: Both of your desired URIs are invalid.  You have 2 protocols, where there should only be 1.  And \ is not a valid character is a URI.

Comment: Why do you think `http://admin:sunil/` is a valid URL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367339/3801327

Comment: Added in-line code blocks for relevant parts of description.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  I am creating the url with http://userid:password@host:port/ ....  In which the password string contains "\" character. So when i construct the url it replaces "\" with %50C and hence the url becomes invalid and not executable.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I am creating the url with userid:password@host:port .... In which the password string contains "\" character. So when i construct the url it replaces "\" with %50C and hence the url becomes invalid and not executable

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Uri.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) class when building URI or URLs. This can save lots of headaches.

```
String s = "sunil\\";
String t = "sunil/";
assertEquals("http://admin:sunil\\",
                new Uri.Builder().scheme("http").authority("admin:" + s).build().toString());
assertEquals("http://admin:sunil/",
                new Uri.Builder().scheme("http").authority("admin:" + t).build().toString());
```

Comment: I am creating the url with userid:password@host:port .... In which the password string contains "\" character. So when i construct the url it replaces "\" with %50C and hence the url becomes invalid and not executable

Comment: I am creating the url with userid:password@host:port .... In which the password string contains "\" character. So when i construct the url it replaces "\" with %50C and hence the url becomes invalid and not executable