# Differences between \W, \\W, [^a-zA-Z0-9_] in regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, escaping

I am trying to find all characters, which are not letters(upper/lowercase), numbers, and underscore, and remove it.

```java
stringA.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]","")   // works perfectly fine
```

However, the following code could not even compile in Java:

```java
stringA.replaceAll("\W","");
// or also
stringA.replaceAll("[\W]","");
// or also
stringA.replaceAll("[\\W]","");
```

If I use only `"\\W"` rather than `"\W"`, the above code turns out to be correct. 
So, what is the differences between `\W`, `\\W`, and when to use brackets like `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: escape the backslash one more time. And don't forget to add semicolon at the last. `stringA.replaceAll("\\W","");`

Comment: Escape the escaper! \ is not only a Regex escape char, it's a Java escape char as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the following code could not even compile in Java

Java has no idea that the string is going to regex engine. Anything in doublequotes is a string literal to Java compiler, so it tries to interpret `\W` as a [*Java escape sequence*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1367322/335858), which does not exist. This trigger a compile-time error.

> If I use only `\\W` rather than `\W`, the above code turns out to be correct.

This is because `\\` is a valid escape sequence, which means "a single slash". When you put two slashes inside a string literal, Java compiler removes one slash, so regex engine sees `\W`, not `\\W`

> So, what is the differences between `\W`, `\\W`, and when to use brackets like `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

The third one is a longer version of the second one; the first one does not compile.