# Getting Backslash index

Tags: java

I need help on getting the index of the backslash.

```
String sms = "dev\project\lastdev\jfile.dll"
```

How do I do something like..

```
int l = sms.lastIndexOf("\")
```

Giving me -1. Which wrong

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile. Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash like this:

```
int index = str.lastIndexOf("\\");
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java) for more info on characters of this kind.