# Regular Expressions example

Tags: java, regex

I’m a bit confused with this example... I don’t understand what is written in this String pattern. Also, what is `find`? I am learning this from TutorialsPoint.

Please, can anyone help me understand it?

Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
        String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
>   Found value: This order was placed for QT300
>   Found value: 0

Comment: Take a look at [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Btw, your question has nothing to do with design-patterns.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html (especially part about greediness) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html.

Comment: If you want it to match the whole number, you can change the regex to `"(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)"`

Comment: i didn't understood how they are matching the string line with "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)" pattern. How this output came like this? Will any one explain this program in briefly?

Comment: Thnqqqqqqqqqqqq for all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern has 3 capture groups

- `(.*)` Means zero or more of any character (Capture group 1)
- `(\\d+)` Means one or more digits (Capture group 2)
- `(.*)` Means zero or more of any character (Capture group 3)

When `find()` is called it "Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern." ([Matcher.Find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html))

When you call these lines:

```
System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
```

- `m.group(0)` Means the entire String the regex evaluated
- `m.group(1)` Refers to capture group 1 (zero or more of any character)
- `m.group(2)` Refers to capture group 2 (one or more digits)
- You're currently not outputting capture group 3 (zero or more of any character)

You'll see that `m.group(1)` returned `This order was placed for QT300` and the last zero was left behind for `m.group(2)` because capture group 2 must have at least 1 digit.

If you were to add capture group 3 (`m.group(3)`) to the output it would display the remaining string after the last zero of `m.group(2)`.

In other words:

```
System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3));
```

Would display:

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
Found value: This order was placed for QT300
Found value: 0
Found value: ! OK?
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup its really help me a lot bro. Thnq so much @Shar1er80

Answer (score 1):

`find()` will find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. Return `true` if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern.

Your regex has 3 group:
`(.*)` is group 1st, `(\\d+)` is group 2nd, `(.*)` is group 3rd.

Group 1st is match 0 or more of the preceding token with any character except line break.

Group 2nd is match 1 or more of the preceding token with any digit character (0-9).

Group 3rd is the same with 1st.

So when your call:

`m.group(0)` will return the entire String.

`m.group(1)` will return the group 1st.

`m.group(2)` will return the group 2nd.

Parameter which is passed into group is index of group in regex.

Comment: Can u explain me about this program? @codeaholicguy

Comment: @Vino as you see in your regex has 3 group (.*) is group 1st, (\\d+) is group 2nd, (.*) is group 3rd. Group 1st is match 0 or more of the preceding token with any character except line break. Group 2nd is match 1 or more of the preceding token with any digit character (0-9). Group 3rd is the same with 1st.

Comment: Tnx @codeaholicguy. So with in the () parameter,that is means for group right ? Ok thn (.*) means for?(is * means for all? Like * in package)  and (\\d+) means for?(Matches digits. Equivalent to [0-9] Right?????? But what is \\d+ ?
Explain me ?

Comment: \\d+ as I said, + is match one or more of the preceding token, \d is any digit character (0 - 9)

Comment: why we are using that with \\d ? Double backslash  means ? and .* too?

Comment: '\\d' because java not understand '\' as backslash character, you must use escape character for it see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java for more information about escape character. '?' is called optional, it mean match between 0 and 1 of the preceding token. '.'  mean match any character except line break. '*' mean match between 0 or more of the preceding token. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for more pattern information.

Comment: Tnx a lot :) Ya now i came to know about backslashes... I studied in escape sequence @code