# Unicode string in Java (Android) not working

Tags: java, android, unicode

I'm making next record in order to compare entered chars with this array:

```
 String[] GSM_7_BIT_EXT = {"\u000c", "\u005e", "\u007b", "\u007d", "\u005c", "\u005b", "\u007e", "\u005d", "\u007c", "\u20ac"};
```

After compile (Android Studio) getting lot of mistakes, like:
- '}' expected
- illegal character: \35
-  expected
and many others.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is `\u005c`: This is the backslash character, therefore `"\u005c"` is equal to `"\"` which is not a valid string literal. (Test this by removing `"\u005c"` from the array definition).

You could write `"\\"` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. Please can you share list of such invalid string literals? Cannot find it in google.

Comment: @GoltsevEugene: the backslashs starts a escape sequence, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367339/3215527, therefore to write a string literal with a backslash character you need to write it as \\.

Comment: What's actually happening is that, unlike all other escape sequences, `\u` is not specific to Strings or chars.  It can appear outside of String and char literals, and is parsed before anything else.  You could, for example, write `\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067[]` instead of `String[]` and it would compile just fine.  That's why `"\u005c"` is equivalent to writing `"\"` in code, which is not legal syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that. But what other symbols are illegal inside String?

Comment: @GoltsevEugene \ and " cannnot simply be placed in a string but need to be escaped.