# Reading and writing data to a file in java with double quotations in the data

Tags: java, string, oop, parsing, file-io

I am having trouble figuring out how to read and write data to and from a file where my values are encapsulated in double quotations.

I am a novice programmer and confused on how to use the pattern regex to get around the issue and am hoping there is another way.

my data file I need to read from is formatted as follows:

```
type = "sedan"
productID = "000123"
price = "30000"
```

Also when I write to the file I need to follow the same format and I cannot figure out how to do it. So far I have the following:

```
PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter("products.txt", "UTF-8");
fileWriter.println("type = " + pTemp.getType + """);
```

which does not work either.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To put a quotation mark in a string, use the escape code [`\"`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367339/5386374).  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Just us the `\` quote to escape the special character `"`

```
PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter("products.txt", "UTF-8");
fileWriter.println("type = \"" + pTemp.getType + "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

To use special characters in java and other similar languages, the usual way is to use a standard escape character `\`.

So for example your code to write the file shall be

```
PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter("products.txt", "UTF-8");
fileWriter.println("type = \"" + pTemp.getType + "\"");
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, it worked! help is greatly appreciated