# Java regex throws java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence for the letter g

Tags: java, regex

I need to see if a whole word exists in a string. This is how I try to do it:

```
if(text.matches(".*\\" + word + "\\b.*"))
    // do something
```

It's running for most words, but words that start with a `g` cause an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3 
.*\great life\b.*
   ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why didn't you wrote it `".*\\b" + word + "\\b.*"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\\` thing proceeded by whatever character will be a interpreted as a metacharacter. E.g. `".*\\geza\\b.*"` will try to find the `\g` escape sequence, `".*\\jani\\b.*"` will try to find `\j`, etc.

Some of these sequences exist, others don't, you can check the [Pattern docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for details. What's really troubling is that probably this isn't what you want.

I agree with [Thomas Ayoub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2307070/thomas-ayoub) that probably you need to match `\\b...\\b` to find a word. I would go one step further and I'd use `Pattern.quote` to avoid unintended regex features that might come from `word`:

```
String text = "Lorem Ipsum a[asd]a sad";
String word = "a[asd]a";
if (text.matches(".*\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b.*")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I don't need the Pattern.quote, it works without it. I'm accepting this answer because of the explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @Eddy However, the solution may turn out much slower if the input string is quite long, as the first `.*` will make the regex engine grab the whole *line* first, and then backtracking will occur trying to find the subsequent patterns. Also, mind that `\b` is a context-dependent pattern, and `".*\\b\\.NET\\b.*"` won't match `.NET` in `This is .NET`. Another downside of this solution is that it won't find a match if the input string has line breaks. [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43616524/3832970) will.

Answer (score 4):

The actual reason for the error is that you cannot escape an alphabetical character in a Java regex pattern that does not form a valid escape construct.

See [Java regex documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language. A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.

I'd use

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b").matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    // A match is found
}
```

If a word may contain/start/end with special chars, I'd use

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?!\\B\\w)" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?<!\\w\\B)").matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    // A match is found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `".*\\" + word + "\\b.*"` with `word = great life` will generate the string `".*\\great life\\b.*"` which, as a value is `.*\great life\b.*`. The issue is that `\g` does not belong to the list of the escape sequences in JAVA (see [What are all the escape characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java))

You can use

```
if(text.matches(".*\\b" + word + "\\b.*"))
                     ^
```

Comment: `String.matches()` is a bit misleading because it tries to match the *entire string* against the regex. Like it would wrap the regex into `^...$` So the `.*` is important in this case.

Comment: @TamasRev thans for the clarification, I've edited accordingly

Comment: Actually, the `\g` error has nothing to do with the escape sequences of Java;  the problem is that it’s not a valid escape sequence in [Java’s regular expression language.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)