# My regex function throws illegal escape exception

Tags: regex, calculator

I want to built a calculator which accepts numbers like 1E100 or 1.34E-200. In order to check if the number entered is acceptable i decided to test the condition with my regex:

```
                              ^-?\\d+\\.?\\d*\\E?\\-?\\d*$
```

however i get an illegal escape and i dont know why? does reges not accept my E?

Comment: `\\E` has no `\\Q` before. Replace `\\E` with `E`

Comment: Do not escape letters. Do not escape **word** characters in the regex when these chars are to be matched *literally*. Also, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43616524/3832970).

Answer (score -1):

You escaped the `E`, which is not necessary :

```
^(-?\d+\.?\d*E?\-?\d*)$
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/VIkHfN/1)