# why CSVWriter and CSVReader uses different default escape characters?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Here is my code snippet which I am using:

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    CSVWriter csvwriter = new CSVWriter(writer);
    String[] originalValues = new String[2];
    originalValues[0] = "t\\est";
    originalValues[1] = "t\\est";
    System.out.println("Original values: " + originalValues[0] +"," + originalValues[1]);
    csvwriter.writeNext(originalValues);

    csvwriter.close();
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(writer.toString()));
    String[] resultingValues = csvReader.readNext();
    System.out.println("Resulting values: " + resultingValues[0] +"," + resultingValues[1]);
```

The output of the above snippet is:

```
Original values: t\est,t\est
Resulting values: test,test
```

Back slash ('\') character is gone after conversion!!!

By some basic analysis I figured that it is happening because `CSVReader` is using Back slash ('\') as default escape character where as `CSVWriter` is using double quote ('"') as default escape character.

*What is the reason behind this inconsistency in default behavior?*

To fix above problem I managed to find following two solutions:

1) Overwriting default escape character of CSVReader with null character:

```
 CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder().withEscapeChar('\0').build();
 CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new StringReader(writer.toString())).withCSVParser(csvParser).build();
```

2) Using RFC4180Parser which strictly follows [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) standards:

```
RFC4180Parser rfc4180Parser = new RFC4180ParserBuilder().build();
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new StringReader(writer.toString())).withCSVParser(rfc4180Parser).build();
```

*Can using any of the above approach cause any side effects on any other characters?*

*Also why `RFC4180Parser` is not default parser? Is it only for maintaining backward compatibility as `RFC4180Parser` got introduced in later versions?*

Comment: CSV 'market' has poor acceptance of standard, I guess for many programmers standard is not known. Many home-brew solution exists with subtle hidden errors. Many business software is build over not-totally-correct formats

Comment: @JacekCz I agree with the fact you mentioned. However I am more curious about the inconsistency in API's default behavior and correctness of the solutions I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Hello Vistal - please check my response in the sourceforge support request you opened.  https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/support-requests/50/

Comment: @ScottConway very well explained on that support request. I wish SOF allows comments to be marked as accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think we are looking at 2 types of escaping here.

**1)** Escaping the double quote in csv:

```
test,"Monitor 24"", Samsung"
test,"Monitor 24\", Samsung"  // Linux style
```

Since we have a comma in the second field, that field has to be surrounded with double quotes. Any double quotes inside that field then have to be escaped, with `""` or `\"`.

**2)** `\` is also a [general escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java), for example `\t` (tab) or `\n` (newline).

And since `'e'` is not in the list of characters to escape, the `\` is simply ignored and removed.

So if you would write `"t\\\\est"` the file would contain `"t\\est"` (escaped backslash) and show `"t\est"` after reading. Or writing `"\\test"` would probably show a `tab` and `"est"` after reading.

To keep the `\` after reading, you would indeed have to tell the parser somehow to ignore those sequences, but the current behaviour doesn't look inconsistent to me - actually they are both treating the `\` as escape character.