# How to search for specific text?

Tags: java

I am unable to search and find specific text from the below string text".

"Size: 0-0
*— 9  otto @ z . t.
— ﬁg se REYfAR, S l '
WELCOME BACK, ELLEN TEST!
..$FREE $l
PICK YOUR " " . @lotto
POWER ' ’-;* A . . . . -
Q9 / '- 32-5 #63333?
.— MILLION I '
/*\ FFfA ﬂ:( MEGAPRIZE @011 €011M$0wm
I ;. .- h ‘ Glmf/immm £95191
¢4 0 """
\nA-—~-"“"'/
_*/
W Match all 8 #'5 plus your Power # to win theJackpot! €® lOttO
391%}; “a 4
5g] PLAY Now 500.00
‘(AY\
Ecuo"

Below is the code i have used which doesn't search for the required text.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.lang.*; 

class GFG 
{ 
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  { 
    // This is a string in which substring 
    // to be searched. 
    String text = "Above text ^"; 

    CharSequence seq = "WELCOME BACK"; 
    boolean bool = text.contains(seq); 
    System.out.println(bool); 


  } 
}
```

Comment: Try just including the text you wish to match, and print out the hash code of both `String`'s

Comment: Can you give me some more insight or provide any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is add escape characters for `\` and `"`, like this... `\\` and `\"`.

```
"Size: 0-0 — 9 otto @ z . t. — ﬁg se REYfAR, S l ' WELCOME BACK, ELLEN TEST! ..$FREE $l PICK YOUR \" \" . @lotto POWER ' ’-; A . . . . - Q9 / '- 32-5 #63333? .— MILLION I ' /\\ FFfA ﬂ:( MEGAPRIZE @011 €011M$0wm I ;. .- h ‘ Glmf/immm £95191 ¢4 0 \"\"\" \nA-—~-\"“\"'/ _/ W Match all 8 #'5 plus your Power # to win theJackpot! €® lOttO 391%}; “a 4 5g] PLAY Now 500.00 ‘(AY\\ Ecuo";
```

> #### Edit
>
> Escape characters are need when a character is used as part of java, so the compiler knows that it is not part of the code however it is part of the String. For instance `"`, it it used by the compiler to indicate the beginning or end of a String. So you need to use an escape character to allow the `"` to be apart of the string. That escape character is the '\' and you do that with a `\"`. Which leads to the second use of escape characters. Say you need to use a `\` in the string, well then you use `\\`.
>
> The String above should contain the corrected escape sequences, that's what worked for me.
>
> [What are all the escape characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters)

Comment: Can you throw some light on where escape characters need to be added? or can you refine my code?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the answers to the questions you just asked me, if you have more questions, please ask. I love answering peoples questions.