# How do I replace the " character in Java?

Tags: java

I read a line from a txt file containing a `string = "abc,""`.

If one wanted to replace string to: `string = "abc"`, one would write

`string = string.replace(",","");` to replace the comma, but how would one replace the `"`?

Problem:

```
string = string.replace(""","");//code does not work because of """
```

Comment: You escape the quote with a backslash by doing `"\""`

Comment: [What are all the escape characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ", so like this:

```
string = string.replace("\"","")
```